# How to check if the variable is moment object in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, error-handling, momentjs

I have a simple scenario where I want to test whether I am sending a string or a number or boolean value instead of a moment object and proceed accordingly.
According to the docs, there is a function called [isMoment()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-a-moment/) which will tell whether the element is a moment object or not. Now this works fine in a browser I tested using a JSfiddle. 
But same doesn't work in NodeJS for the same version 2.13.0
This line `console.log(moment.isMoment("String"));` outputs false in browser but in NodeJS outputs

```
Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
Arguments: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback (/home/oroborus/vehico-api-business/node_modules/moment/moment.js:271:105)
```

and execution stops. How do I proceed here?
I read the issue. What they are saying is right that you cannot convert date string reliably to moment and hence the deprecation warning but then how do I test if whatever i am sending if it's a moment object then proceed if not return without a proper message.

Here is the code

```
 if (req.body.startDate === "" || req.body.endDate === "" || req.body.driverId === "") {
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
            message: "Empty strings not allowed"
        }));

    } else if (req.body.startDate === null || req.body.endDate === null || req.body.driverId === null) {
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
            message: "Null values are not allowed"
        }));
    } else if (moment.isMoment(req.body.startDate) || moment.isMoment(req.body.endDate)) {
        console.log("This is not working :( );
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
            message: "Only moment objects are allowed"
        }));
    } else {

      //The rest of the procedure
    }
```

Comment: log the value of req.body.startDate and tell me what exactly it contains

Comment: "A string" for testing purpose but actually a moment object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with moment, your last condition is not good. moment is failing like it should because the else branch is executed when the input dates are NOT moment objects.

```
if (req.body.startDate === "" || req.body.endDate === "" || req.body.driverId === "") {
    res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
        message: "Empty strings not allowed"
    }));
} else if (req.body.startDate === null || req.body.endDate === null || req.body.driverId === null) {
    res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
        message: "Null values are not allowed"
    }));
// ------------ you forgot ! here
} else if (!moment.isMoment(req.body.startDate) || !moment.isMoment(req.body.endDate)) {
    console.log("This is not working :( )";
    res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
        message: "Only moment objects are allowed"
    }));
} else {
    //The rest of the procedure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers I found out while reading the docs thoroughly(Sorry my bad I didn't do it earlier). There is a line [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) which says

> If a string does not match any of the above formats and is not able to
>   be parsed with Date.parse, moment#isValid will return false.

`moment("not a real date").isValid();`

which after printing a warning in node returns `false`.